# SQL for Splitting a string by hyphen, and then generating all the suffixes for each chunk that is 3 or more chars in length?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a Prefix Search engine, and I am trying to generate suffix keywords for my part numbers.

**Example String: `123456-7890-A-BCDEF-GHIJ-KL`

I am looking to split this string into chunks, like this:

```
  123456
  7890
  A
  BCDEF
  GHIJ
  KL
```

Then I need to generate the suffixes of each chunk that is more that 3 chars in length, into one comma delimited list.

> --For chunk 123456, I would get the suffixes 23456, 3456, 456, 56
>
> --For chunk 7890, I would get the suffixes 890, 90
>
> --For chunk A, it would be ignored as it is less than 3 chars in Length
>
> --For chunk BCDEF, I would get the suffixes CDEF, DEF, EF
>
> --For chunk GHIJ, I would get the suffixes HIJ, IJ
>
> --For chunk KL, it would be ignored as it is less than 3 chars in Length

My string could have any amount of chars in each chunk, they are not always formatted like the example.

So the final result for string `123456-7890-A-BCDEF-GHIJ` would look like this;

```
23456, 3456, 456, 56, 890, 90, CDEF, DEF, EF, HIJ, IJ
```

My string could have any amount of chars in each chunk, they are not always formatted like the example.
Some other example strings;

```
123-4567890-ABC-DEFGHIJ-K-L

--Result: 23, 567890, 67890, 7890, 890, 90, BC, EFGHIJ, FGHIJ, GHIJ, HIJ, IJ

123456-7-890AB-CDEFG-H-IJKL

--Result: 23456, 3456, 456, 56, 90AB, 0AB, AB, DEFG, EFG, FG, JKL, KL
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Not much unfortunately. I started working through it in Excel just to get an idea of how the nested if statements would be structured;

=CONCAT(IF(LEN(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1)-1))=3,RIGHT(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1)-1),2),IF(LEN(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1)-1))=4,CONCAT(RIGHT(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1)-1),2),", ",RIGHT(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1)-1),3)),"")),IF(LEN(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1))))=4,RIGHT(LEFT(C2,SEARCH("-",C2,1)-1),2)),"NEXT")

Comment: I think it's possible that there's a better way of approaching this that I may not be thinking of.

Comment: I would probably create a procedure that determines each of the appropriate values and loads each value as a row in a staging table.  Then ```PIVOT``` the table and concatenate all values into a comma separated list.  Part of the challenge on the extraction side will be how to deal with the inconsistent number of strings and related suffixes.

Comment: What database platform and version are you using? If you are using SQL Server 2017 or higher here is a [start](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba0ab4d45cf7b1d57af1c2a743f895af).

Comment: "Then I need to generate the suffixes of each chunk that is more that 3 chars in length" is unclear. For `123456` you want `23456`, `3456`, `456` and `56`. Why not `6`? Or why `56` if you want "suffixes more that _[sic]_ 3 chars in length"?

Comment: Well Bueller?  Some good ideas have been submitted to you.

Comment: For sure, I just need a chance to try some out. I appreciate everyone's input and will update as I try implementing the ideas submitted.

Comment: HABO, I want to process only the "chunks" that are 3 chars or over in length, not suffixes.
Those are the ones that I need to generate the suffixes down to 2 chars. I hope that helps clear that up.

Comment: I'm not 100% on the version of SQL. This is for a Saved Export within Volusion.
I will try to find out from them...

Comment: This is for a Saved Export within Volusion.
They use sql server web 2017 sp2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I acknowledge this is not quite what you are looking for, but it is close. Perhaps this will give you or someone else an idea to get exactly what you want. This assumes SQL Server 2017 or higher.

So I am using [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to divide the string into one row for each chunk numbering those rows using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). There is a problem with this in that STRING_SPLIT() does not guarantee order.

I then use a CTE to basically come up with index values to step through the each chunk from 2 to chunk length - 1 putting those strings back into a comma-separated list for each chunk using [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

I insert those results to a temp table so that I can select them in order by row number and assemble the suffixes from each chunk into the final comma-separated list.

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(50);
SET @MyString = '123456-7890-A-BCDEF-GHIJ';

WITH   cte
AS     (SELECT 
          2 AS n -- anchor member
        , value 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS [rn]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@MyString, '-')
        WHERE LEN(value) >= 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
          n + 1
          , cte.value -- recursive member
          , cte.rn
        FROM   cte
        WHERE  n < (LEN(value) - 1) -- terminator
       )
SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(value, n, LEN(value) - n + 1), ', ') as [Chunk]
INTO #Temp
FROM   cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;

SELECT STRING_AGG(Chunk, ', ')
FROM #Temp
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fc00c2a67ffcf4bc6b61cecafe7ba3d).

Comment: Thank you, I am very busy, but I will try this ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this and likely better string manipulators than t-sql, but this seems to work: (requires DB to be compatibility mode = SQL 2016 or above to use STRING_SPLIT)

```
DECLARE @STRING     VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @DIVIDEON   CHAR (1)
DECLARE @FULLSTRING VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @SUBSTR     VARCHAR (100) 
DECLARE @WRKSTRING  VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @LEN        TINYINT

SELECT  @STRING = '123456-7-890AB-CDEFG-H-IJKL'
SELECT  @DIVIDEON = '-'
SELECT  @FULLSTRING =''

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #mytable     

select RIGHT(value,LEN(value)-1) as MyString 
into #mytable
from STRING_SPLIT (@STRING, @DIVIDEON)  -- only SQL 2016 and above
where len(value)>2 -- ignore subsets that do not have 3 or more chars

while exists (select MyString from #mytable)
begin
   select @WRKSTRING = (select top 1 MyString from #mytable)
   select @LEN = len(@WRKSTRING)
   select @SUBSTR=@WRKSTRING
   while @LEN>2
   begin
      select @SUBSTR=@SUBSTR+', '+RIGHT(@WRKSTRING,@LEN-1)
      select @LEN=@LEN-1
   end
   delete from #mytable where MyString = @WRKSTRING
   --select @SUBSTR as Fullstr
   select @FULLSTRING=@FULLSTRING+@SUBSTR+','

end
   select LEFT(@FULLSTRING,LEN(@FULLSTRING)-1)
drop table #mytable
```

Comment: Thank you, I am very busy, but I will try this ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

--not performant...maybe good enough(?)

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity primary key clustered,
thecol varchar(40)
);

insert into @t(thecol)
values('1-2-3-4-5-6'), ('abcd') /*??*/;

insert into @t(thecol)
select top (10000) newid()
from master.dbo.spt_values as a
cross join master.dbo.spt_values as b;

select *,
thelist= replace(
cast('<!--'+replace(thecol, '-', '--><!--')+'-->' as xml).query('
let $seq := (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) (: note: max 22 chars per string-part:)
for $a in comment()
  let $str := string($a), $maxlen := string-length($str)-1
  for $i in $seq[. <= $maxlen]
    return concat(substring($str, $i, 100), "," )
').value('.', 'varchar(max)')+'_', ',_', '')
from @t;
```

Comment: Thank you, I am very busy, but I will try this ASAP!